# The JTextfield doesn't show like I want

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm new to Java and I can't find a simple solution. In the image below, you can see what my problem is. I want to write a program, where I can create playlists and safe them, but I am already stuck at the beginning because the `JTextfield` is too small.

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame w = new Layout();
        w.setVisible(true);
        w.setSize(600, 600);
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        w.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Layout extends JFrame{

        JTextField input;
    
    Layout(){   
        
        //title and layout type
        super("ThePlay");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        JButton s;  //search button
        JButton h;  //home button
        JButton mp; //my playlist button
        JButton cp; //create playlist button
        JButton fs; //favorite songs button

        //frame constructor
        Container mainContainer = this.getContentPane();
        mainContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,6));
        mainContainer.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        this.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.GRAY));
        
        //input constructor
        input = new JTextField();
        input.setBounds(300, 50, 150, 25);
        
        //up frame
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(6));
        
        //bot frame
        JPanel downPanel = new JPanel();
        downPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
        downPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        downPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(5));
        
        //create buttons
        s = new JButton("Search");
        h = new JButton("Home");
        mp = new JButton("My Playlists");
        cp = new JButton("Create Playlist");
        fs = new JButton("Favorite Songs");
        
        
        //add buttons to the frame
        mainContainer.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);     //top frame location
        mainContainer.add(downPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);   //bottom frame location
        topPanel.add(input);
        topPanel.add(s);
        topPanel.add(h);
        topPanel.add(mp);
        topPanel.add(cp);
        topPanel.add(fs);   
    }
}
```

[image: The issue is shown here]

Comment: *"I can't find a simple solution"* [Reading the (fine) manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextField.html#<init>(int)) isn't that difficult. Checking the documentation (and tutorial) is something you should always do before asking a question on SO.

Answer (score 7):

You can give to the `JTextField` a size in this way:

```
input = new JTextField(20);
```

**From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html):**

> The integer argument passed to the JTextField constructor, 20 in the
> example, indicates the number of columns in the field. This number is
> used along with metrics provided by the field's current font to
> calculate the field's preferred width. It does not limit the number of
> characters the user can enter.

Comment: @Hunglaublich if you found it helpful you can accept it as a solution using the green check

Answer (score 0):

When the int in the constructor is to big the JTextField will bug

I think it's depend of the size of the container.

here if i write 10 instead of 5 it's doesn't work:

```
Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
dim.width = 150;
setPreferredSize(dim);
        
nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
nameField = new JTextField(5);
```